# How reopen an already running node-webkit window app?

Tags: javascript, node-webkit

I currently have a node-webkit app for Mac and Windows. When you close the window, the app keeps running in the background and can be reopened trough the system tray.

I would like to let my users open the window from the executable (think the shortcut to the .exe on the desktop).

On Mac, I did this to allow users to open the window from the Dock :

```
var gui = require('nw.gui');

gui.App.on('reopen', function() {
    win.show();
});
```

But, according to the documentation, the 'reopen' event is a Mac only feature.

Is it possible to have the same behaviour on Windows ? How ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is no reopen feature provided for windows yet, but an alternative would be to use `window.hide()` and tray features as described in [Tray](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/Tray).
In my application I have created custom buttons for minimise, maximise and close and provided following functions for them:

```
var gui = require('nw.gui');
var window = gui.Window.get();  
var isMaximised = false;

//Minimise:  
minimise: function(){
    window.hide();
    var tray = new gui.Tray({title: 'Tray'});
    var menuTray = new gui.Menu();
    menuTray.append(new gui.MenuItem({ label : 'quit',
      click: function(){
        window.close();
      }
    }));
    tray.menu = menuTray;

    tray.on('click',function(){
      tray.remove();
      window.show();
      tray = null;
    });
}  

//Maximise  
maximise: function(){  
  if (isMaximized) {
    isMaximized = false;
    window.unmaximize();
  } else {
    isMaximized = true;
    window.maximize();
  }
}  

 //Close  
close: function(){  
   window.hide();
   var tray = new gui.Tray({title: 'Tray'});
   var menuTray = new gui.Menu();
   menuTray.append(new gui.MenuItem({ label : 'quit',
       click: function(){
       tray.remove();
       window.close();
       }
   }));
   tray.menu = menuTray;
   tray.on('click',function(){
     tray.remove();
     window.show();
     tray = null;
   });
}
```

So on close of application by clicking close button, it hides app and creates a menuItem in tray(Dock). On click of icon in dock, it shows application back to user.
Only way application can be closed now is by doing a right-click on dock item and selecting quit button which closes application.

Answer (score 1):

i had the issue and i have fix it using listen to open not reopen, here is simple code for your desktop case
simple manifest Json "package.json" :

```
{
  "main": "index.html",
  "name": "reopen from Desktop",
  "window":
  {
  "width": 300,
  "height": 200
  }
}
```

then a simple index.html file

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script>
   var gui = require('nw.gui');
   var win = gui.Window.get();
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <script>
   //list to open and make the app show
   gui.App.on('open', function() {
   win.show();
   alert("file re-open");
   });

   // prevent close and make it hide
   win.on('close', function() {
   win.hide(); 
   });
  </script>
  <!-- forse close the app -->
   <center><br><br><input type="button" value="exit app" onclick="win.close(true)"></center>
  </body>
 </html>
```

then copy and past the node-webkit files for window on the same directory like normal package way then rename nw.exe to reopen.exe for example and then right click and create a desktop shortcut and open the exe file from the folder and click on close which will hide it then click on the desktop shortcut and it will re-show it "re-open" with an alert